# Get index of list item inside of original list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

I have a list which is similar to the one below:

`l = [["abc", 4, 3], ["def", 0, 0], ["ghi", 1, 2], ["def", 0, 0]]`

I set a variable to `l[1]`. Would it be possible to get the index of this variable in the original list considering there are duplicates?

Example return value: 1 (because the variable I set was `l[1]`)

Comment: *Would it be possible to get the index of this variable in the original list considering there are duplicates?*, Can you explain this?

Comment: May you add an example of expected result?

Comment: @ALai Added to question. (It would be 1 because I set the variable to l[1])

Comment: I'd say the answer is no. You can go through the list to get the index of the item you know, but if there're duplicates there's no way to get the index 100% reliably. But why don't you just store the index of the item instead?

Comment: @RomanPekar In the full program, there would be multiple of these nested inside of each other, which would make it extremely complicated to store each index.

Comment: storing list of indexes then?

Comment: @RomanPekar No, that's not the point of the question.

Comment: If there are duplicates, I would just store in the variable a tuple with the index and the list, instead of just the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I understand correctly:

```
l = [["abc", 4, 3], ["def", 0, 0], ["ghi", 1, 2], ["def", 0, 0]]
item = l[3]
assert l.index(item) == 3  # this won't work because l.index(item) will return 1
```

You expect this to work, but it doesn't cause item index 1 is the same as item index 3.

You probably should use a different data structure for this problem. However you can try to use object identity comparison to find the exact same list, instead of object equality, which will match with a different list that contains the same items. E.g., like this:

```
l = [["abc", 4, 3], ["def", 0, 0], ["ghi", 1, 2], ["def", 0, 0]]
item = l[3]
assert next(index for index, candidate in enumerate(l) if candidate is item) == 3
```

This works because the `is` operator uses [object identity comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not) to find the actual list refered to by `item`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question You want to have indexes of all duplicates. You can do it like that

```
for x,y in enumerate(l):
    if y == value:
         index.append(x)
```

If you want just first index you can use

```
list.index(value)
```

It will return first occurence of the value

Comment: Yes, except that this code won't return *which* index of the duplicates it actually was.

Comment: It willl create a list of indexes that value and its duplicates are on in the list passed as 'l'